# Bootstrap: dropdown vs button dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap documentation, there seems to be two different ways to create a dropdown:

- `.dropdown`
- `.btn-group`

The [first](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example) is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

The [second](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single) is as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown 
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is one way preferred over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are basically the same, the use of btn group is to ensure that you can get the buttons on a single line with either another button or another form element.